Can I travel to Pakistan if my Pakistani passport expires in 20 days?
Can I travel to Pakistan if my Pakistani passport expires in 20 days?

Please review the Answer of Jörg W Mittag to this Travel.SE question. The facts are a bit different, but the challenge —  getting to Pakistan — is the same.

A citizen of a country is always allowed to travel to and enter their own country up to the very last day of validity of their passport (and sometimes even beyond, but that’s a lot more complex situation).
It’s only when you travel to another country that you may encounter minimum passport validities (because they want to be sure you can exit the country and return home).
Make sure you check the rules for any transit countries, though.

A citizen may be allowed to enter their country but the airline can still deny them boarding if the destination country has sets rules around this (even if these rules are in conflict existing laws).  A prime example is the US: a US citizen doesn't need a passport to enter the country, but they do need one to board a US bound plane. US CBP uses the airlines to enforce rules that they cannot legally enforce themselves.  I have no idea about Pakistan though.

@Hilmar This is what makes the "expired passport" situation a lot more complex: you may be able to enter (if you manage to reach the border) but not travel to (because the airline won't let your board) your own country in this situation. Ditto for missing passport and the like. But for a valid passport, it will always be valid for both travel to and entry into your own country, any "minimum validity" rules only apply to foreigners.

@Hilmar there is a statutory requirement for US citizens to have a valid US passport to enter the US; it's just that there is an (implicit) constitutional requirement to let them in if they don't have one.  Consequently, the immigration officer has to waive the statutory requirement.  The technical legal framework is sufficiently convoluted that TIMATIC shows (and therefore airlines enforce) a requirement to have a passport that is valid on arrival.
